# как использовать *args и **kwargs в pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Функция принимает аргументы `*args` и `departments: tuple = None`. Как можно написать на нее тесты используя pytest?

```
test_data = (
    (('Develop', [1000, 200, 500]),
     ('Marketing', [400, 600, 300]),
     ('Sales', [500, 700, 100]),
     {'expected': ([1000, 700, 600], 53.49)},
    ),
    ((), ([], 0.00)),
)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('args, expected', test_data)
def test_get_top_salaries(*args: Tuple[str, list], expected: tuple):
    assert get_top_salaries(args) == expected
```

Выдает:

```
____________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_hw1.py ____________________________________________________________________________
test_hw1.py::test_get_top_salaries: in "parametrize" the number of names (2):
  ['args', 'expected']
must be equal to the number of values (4):
  (('Develop', [1000, 200, 500]), ('Marketing', [400, 600, 300]), ('Sales', [500, 700, 100]), {'expected': ([1000, 700, 600], 53.49)})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
([1000, 700, 600], 53.49)
============================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================
ERROR test_hw1.py - Failed: test_hw1.py::test_get_top_salaries: in "parametrize" the number of names (2):
```

Comment: А зачем? Что мешает вместо `*args` использовать просто `args`?

Comment: тоже не работает.

Comment: Ну, чтобы заработало хоть как-то, надо для начала вместо чуши в test_data написать что-то внятное) pytest вам говорит, что он должен содержать элементы по два элемента в каждом (для args и expected соответственно), а у вас в test_data первый элемент это кортеж почему-то аж с четырьмя элементами

Comment: понял, заработало, спасибо

Comment: args должно быть просто аргументом без звездочки, а уже в тестируемую функцию (если она предполагает распаковку в отдельные аргументы) - передавать со звездочкой.